# Toggle key in P5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I'd like to use the same key to trigger different events, basically to use it in "toggle" mode.

For example, I'd like that when 'N' is pressed once, it executes noLoop() and when it is pressed again, it then executes loop(), so I could use it as a kind of pause/play key.

for now my code looks like this and of course it doesn't work as the two "if" statements are executed back to back :

```
function keyTyped(){

    let n =0;

    if (key == 'n' && n == 0 ){
    noLoop();
    n = 255;
    print(n);
    }

    if (key == 'n' && n == 255){
        print("success");
        loop();
        n = 0;
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To make `n` control looping make these changes:

1. Move the declaration of `n` out of the `keyTyped` function so it will maintain state.
2. Change the two `if` conditions to an `if` `else`

```js
let n = 0;
let cnt = 0;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw(){
    console.log("looping " + cnt++);
}
function keyTyped(){
    if (key == 'n' && n == 0 ){
      noLoop();
      n = 255;
    } else if (key == 'n' && n == 255){
        loop();
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```